# Find all contracts that are active for at least 90 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to find all CIDs (Contracts) meet the following conditions

1. They are active between Jan 01 2011 and June 30 2011 (can start before or after the cutoff start date, and can end before or after the cutoff end date), but they have to be active between those dates
2. They are active for at least 90 days between Jan 01 2011 and June 30 2011

The only solution I can think of is `unpivot` so that there is a 1 for each day in the date range, and 0 for the days outside that range. Then we can sum up the 1's and if it is greater than the num of days in the first six months of 2011, then include that contract.

Is there a better way?

Here is how to generate the data

```
      Select CID = 5439, ContractStartTime = '2008-06-26 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-01-29 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 6216, ContractStartTime = '2008-07-02 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2010-12-02 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 7770, ContractStartTime = '2008-12-03 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2010-12-01 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 12432, ContractStartTime = '2009-12-17 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2010-12-15 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 13986, ContractStartTime = '2009-05-11 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2011-05-09 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 14763, ContractStartTime = '2009-12-28 09:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-03-25 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 16317, ContractStartTime = '2010-12-08 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2011-12-06 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 20979, ContractStartTime = '2010-10-14 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-12-12 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 17871, ContractStartTime = '2010-01-20 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-01-19 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 19425, ContractStartTime = '2010-02-23 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-02-21 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 21756, ContractStartTime = '2010-12-28 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-12-25 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 20202, ContractStartTime = '2011-02-24 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-05-02 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 22533, ContractStartTime = '2010-12-27 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2011-01-26 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 23310, ContractStartTime = '2010-06-21 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2011-06-21 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 24864, ContractStartTime = '2010-07-25 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-12-26 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 27195, ContractStartTime = '2011-01-11 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2013-01-09 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 27972, ContractStartTime = '2011-01-04 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2013-01-02 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 29526, ContractStartTime = '2011-01-28 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-01-29 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 33411, ContractStartTime = '2011-04-28 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2011-04-27 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 34965, ContractStartTime = '2011-06-14 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-06-11 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 35742, ContractStartTime = '2011-06-07 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2011-07-06 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 39627, ContractStartTime = '2012-01-12 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2013-01-10 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 40404, ContractStartTime = '2011-11-30 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-07-29 00:00:00.000'
UNION Select CID = 48951, ContractStartTime = '2012-06-21 00:00:00.000', ContractStopTime  = '2012-07-22 00:00:00.000'
Order by 3
```

Comment: Do you need CID's where their active times has 90 days in the window January to June?  Or where the active period is at least 90 days long, and that at least 1 of those days is in January to June?

Comment: Can you provide some DDL so we can replicate your environment?

Comment: I need CID's for contracts that are active for at least 90 days between Jan 1 and June 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CID's that have 90 active days in the window January to June...

```
DECLARE
  @windowStart DATETIME,
  @windowEnd   DATETIME
SELECT
  @windowStart = '20110101',
  @windowEnd   = '20110701'

SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
      contractStopTime  >= @windowStart
  AND contractStartTime <  @windowEnd
  AND DATEDIFF(
        DAY,
        CASE WHEN ContractStartTime >= @windowStart THEN contractStartTime ELSE @windowStart END,
        CASE WHEN ContractStopTime  <  @windowEnd   THEN contractStopTime  ELSE @windowEnd   END
      ) >= 90
```

Comment: seems like the values initialized are swapped with each other? stop time should be by june ?

Comment: @Kanavi - No, my personal belief on best practice for dates is to use `>= AND <`. In this case I have used `< '20110701'` which is everything before July 1st 2011. No matter what data-type or time component is used, this ensures that *all* of June is included.